# Append to tar file with performance

Tags: python, python-3.x, tarfile

As you might know python's `tarfile` have not ability to append to compressed files as `gz` or `bz2`. I tried to implement this functionality which works fine but has slow speed. The following code just accepts a string or bytes and append it as a file to an existing tarfile. I'm not sure if this code has the best performance but may have issues. I also tried to write files to memory instead of temp directory but I got the same performance.

```
import os
import tarfile
import tempfile
import time
from pathlib import Path


def append_tar_file(buffer, file_name, output_path, replace=True):
    """
    append a buffer to an existing tar file
    """
    # extract files
    # check for existing file and overwrite if need to
    # compress files
    if not os.path.isfile(output_path):
        return
    buffer = buffer.encode("utf-8") if isinstance(buffer, str) else buffer

    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
        tempdirp = Path(tempdir)
        with tarfile.open(output_path, "r:bz2") as tar:
            try:
                tar.extractall(os.path.abspath(tempdirp))
            except Exception as err:   #tar file is empty
                print(err)
        buffer_path = os.path.join(tempdir, os.path.basename(file_name))
        if replace or (buffer_path not in list(os.path.abspath(f) for f in tempdirp.iterdir())):
            with open(buffer_path, "wb") as f:
                f.write(buffer)

        with tarfile.open(output_path, "w:bz2") as tar:
            for file in tempdirp.iterdir():
                try:
                    tar.add(file, arcname=os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(file)))
                except Exception as err:
                    print(err)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = "./test.tar.gz"
    buffer = "Test String"
    filename = "somefile"
    for i in range(1, 100):
        print(time.time())
        append_tar_file(buffer, filename+str(i), path)
```

Comment: Do you mean that you've tried [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/mmap.html)? Also please run some benchmarks and tell us which line is causing problem.

Comment: @Kasramvd No, I only tried BytesIO.

Comment: What is you actual question? Please remember that [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is our sibling site for reviewing and optimization of working code.

Comment: I just wanted to make the append mode functionality for better performance. If you run the code you can see when the file gets larger it took more time to append. I thought maybe there are better approaches to do that.